# Mongodb MapReduce converts all integer values as double

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce

```
string map = @"
function() {
    var doc = this;
    emit(doc._id, { name:doc.name, version: doc.version, type: doc.type, date: doc.date });
}";
var result = _collection.MapReduce(map, "").GetResults()
```

Code is in C#

Here doc.type and doc.date both are stored as integers in the database; but when I check the values of variable result, then I find all the integer values have been apeneded with .0 basically turned to double values.

Does anyone have an idea what is the matter here and why does it convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce is JavaScript, and JavaScript doesn't have a true Integer type, just a "Number" type which is basically a double. Hence, the results come back as doubles whenever you perform any number arithmetic using M/R.

You will have to convert them back to Integer by parsing them in C#. Keep in mind that doubles don't have perfect precision, so adding 1 to a *very large number* might not actually be representable, i.e. `X + 1 === X` for very large X.

Comment: You could always cast the MapReduceResult type as a class to do this.